# Generating version information in Matlab (Matlab Compiler)

Tags: matlab, dll, version-control, compiler-construction

I am currently generating some DLL (dot net) by using the Matlab Compiler.
For my own sake, I would like to add a version information to my DLL (that will be visible in the setting information)

Could someone explain to me the steps that I have to follow to do such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Check this one](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-2GWE9P/)

Title: How can I specify version information for a DLL compiled with Microsoft Visual C/C++ Compiler in MATLAB 7.13 (R2011b)?